# How can you bind with Knockout without using the html attribute tag data-bind value?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Normally with KnockoutJs you would have something like this:

```
    <input type="text" name="Capital" id="Capital" data-bind="value: capital">
```

During the binding, we would create an observable:

```
   this.capital = ko.observable(100);
```

But let's say that we cannot add the data-bind attribute. Also not after page is loaded..and after that.. never.

How would we be able to bind to our viewmodel using Knockout ?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to add the `data-bind` markup to the elements, you need to either write your own custom bindingProvider that lets you write the bindings in javscript, or you could use the [Knockout.Unobtrusive](http://bsatrom.github.com/Knockout.Unobtrusive/) plugin, which gives you this functionality.

Comment: The Knockout Unobstrusive does add the data-value attribute behind the scenes, so that is not an option.Need to see how to manage this via a custom bindingProvider..

Comment: I see. I also found this https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/knockoutjs/kfM2zJ1Nv2o/hmBT2t7m0kwJ which mentions the custom binding provider used in the announcement of the ko 2.0 release (http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/12/21/knockout-2-0-0-released/).